# Inner Join two dataframes does not sort properly - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, inner-join

I am trying to merge two dataframes on inner join and append the values and I was able to perform the join but for some reason the values are ordered properly in each column.

To explain more about this,

1. Please find the below screenshot where my first dataframe has the stored values of each column

[image]

2. My second dataframe has the string values which needs to be replaced with the values stored in my dataframe 1 above.

[image]

Below is the output that I have got but when you look at the values and compare with dataframe 2, they are not assigned properly, For eg:If you consider row 1 in dataframe 2, the Column 1 should have value(i.e. secind column in Dataframe 2) 1.896552 but in my outut I have something else.

[image]

Below is the code I worked with to achive the above result.

```
Joined_df_wna_test = pd.DataFrame()

for col in Unseen_cleaned_rmv_un_2:
    Joined_data = pd.merge(Output_df_unseen, my_dataframe_categorical, on=col,  how='inner')
    Joined_df = pd.DataFrame(Joined_data)
    Joined_df_wna_test[col]= Joined_df.Value
    Joined_df_wna_test
Joined_df_wna_test
```

Could someone please help me in overcoming this issue this?

Answer (score 0):

Found Answer for this
The how='left' part is what actually makes it keep the order
Joined_data = Unseen_cleaned_rmv_un.merge(my_dataframe_categorical, on=col, how='left')